# How can i send and get jsonweb token in a browser

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

How can i send and get jsonweb token in a browser? I need to send on every forbidden page token after user has signed in.

I have code and everything works fine in a postman but when i try in a browser `req.headers["authorization"]` is always undefined. I was also trying to `res.set({'token': 'some token'});` and then request in the next page but still undefined. There is a lot tutorial with postman but I can figure out how can I do this in a browser.
Here is my code:

```
app.post("/api/login", function(req, res) {
var user = { id: 3 };
var token = jwt.sign({ user }, 'secret');
res.json({token: token});
```

});

```
app.get('/api/protected', ensureToken, function(req, res) {
jwt.verify(req.token, 'secret_key_goes_here', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        res.sendStatus(403);
    } else {
        res.json({
            description: 'Protected information. Congrats!'
        });
    }
});
```

});

```
function ensureToken(req, res, next) {
const token = req.headers["authorization"];
console.log(token);
if (typeof bearerHeader !== 'undefined') {
    console.log('ok');
    const berarer = bearerHeader.split(" ");
    const bearerToken = berarer[1];
    req.token = bearerToken;
    next();
} else {
    console.log('no');
    res.sendStatus(403);
}
```

}

Please, any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what front-end framework you are using, if you are using one.

Comment: jquery for example...

Comment: You can use cookies, set it using `res.cookie(name, value, option)` and check in `ensureToken` with `req.cookies[name]` or `req.signedCookies[name]`, depending on whether you singed the cookie or not